# chosen jquery - multiselect not working to enable options which are disabled

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to use chosen jQuery in my project .. issue i am facing is as below.

I am having drop down with continents as well as countries in same drop down.

The scenario is .....  If i select Asia it should disable all countries(i.e.India) related to Asia. and if i deselect Asia then all related countries of Asia should be enabled.

And how is it working is ...... when i select Asia it disables Asia but its not effecting any related countries of Asia and all countries are enabled.

Comment: Can you share the JS and HTML code?

Comment: Please share relevant code.. If possible make a plnkr or fiddle and try to reproduce the behavior. That would help everyone in contributing and helping.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use optgrouts for the desired behaviour, f.e. http://jsfiddle.net/jphase/A6LBv/

```html
<select name="optselect[]" multiple="multiple">
  <optgroup label="Asia">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Europe">
    <option>4</option>
    <option>5</option>
    <option>6</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

Please note that it will select/deselect all children of an optgroup, not the optgroup itself.

Comment: Thanks mate :)

This is what i was looking for. But following is my exact requirement

<select name="optselect[]" multiple="multiple">
 <optgroup label="All">
  <option>All</option>
 <optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Asia">
  <option>India</option>
  <option>China</option>
 </optgroup>
</select>

in above drop down 
1) If i select All then every options should be disabled
2) If i select only Asia then India and China should get disabled and in selection box only Asia should come ( as of now India and China are coming)

Can we get optgroup label name any how ?

Comment: I don't think there is a default handling for this requirement, but you can implement it by yourself by handling the change event by yourself @see http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/options.html#triggered-events